# how can i access the depth information from an image taken with a mobile (Honor view20) having time of flight camera?

Tags: image, camera

I have Honor view 20 and I want to access depth information from any picture taken by the time of flight camera. When I check the images with open cv, I found it only RGB

Comment: What have you tried so far? What programing language a you want to use? (Sounds like a job for python)

Comment: @Yonlif I use python. I took a normal image using the mobile. I didn't find any depth information neither in the metadata nor in the file body. It was a normal RGB image.